# Finding dynamically named elements on a page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to locate and click on a section of a web page using Selenium so I can add a comment. I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do this, though.

It seems like the `class` of the element changes from page-to-page. It also doesn't help that there are multiple similar elements in the document. Here's what I've come up so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/me/Library/Application/Support/Google/Chrome/Default")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://link-i-want-to-visit")
comment_section = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//input"))
print comment_section
comment_section.click()
```

Here's some of the markup from the relevant page:

```
<input class="sc-iKpIOp igoGaM" placeholder="Add a comment…">
```

On each different URL on this site, the class name appears to change. How can I circumvent that limitation, click into the input field, and send my comment?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. If it helps, this input field *appears* to be the last on the page, but I don't know if that's relevant (semantically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use absolute xpath not including class?

e.g. /html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/p[1] is your "I'm trying to..." paragraph on this page.

Also, try //input[placeholder="Add a comment…"]

Comment: This solution should work if the dynamically named elements which OP is looking for are always in the same place. I would suggest you describe how to find the xpath of an element because most people do not know how to find it

Comment: @Jamesdeluk that solution doesn't appear to work (see SPYBUY96s comment). Do you have any other alternatives? Sorry if this question comes across as ignorant. I have used Selenium much.

Comment: Apologies; I am also fairly new.

For xpath, I use a Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) and experiment. Of course, it won't work if the xpath changes for each page (which is hard for me to know without knowing the actual URLs in question).

Does the placeholder attribute selector not work either?

Comment: @Jamesdeluk the xpath mgiht not actually change, but the placeholder attribute selector appears to not work either.

Comment: This helped more than anything else, although I did have to do a little digging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`comment_section = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input")`

This will return list.So you can't click on list. You should use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input")` to click on the element.

However for a best practice Use  [**WebDriverWait**](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and Wait for the element `element_to_be_clickable`
and then click.

```
comment_section=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Add a comment…']")))
comment_section.click()
```

OR

```
comment_section=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@placeholder,'Add a comment')]")))
comment_section.click()
```

You need to use following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```